# Select Items that don't have matching Items in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
                          Tables
 _________________________       _________________________
|__________items__________|     |_______readStatus________|
|___itemId___|____data____|     |___itemId___|___status___|
| 1          | cats       |     | 1          | 1          |
| 2          | dogs       |     | 2          | 1          |
| 3          | fish       |     |            |            |
 -------------------------       -------------------------
```

I have two MySQL tables similar to like shown above. I need to get entries from the `item` table that don't have a corresponding `status` `1` in the `readStatus` table. So in this example I need the entry where `data` is `fish`. I'm not very familiar with SQL so I'm not exactly sure how to get about this but based on other questions I've come up with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items
INNER JOIN
readStatus
ON  items.itemId = readStatus.itemId
WHERE readStatus.status != 1
```

This does not work though because it skips any entries in the `items` table that don't have a matching entry in the `readStatus` table. Adding `status` `0` entries to search for isn't an option because it would eventually create millions of entries. Also it looks like, in phpMyAdmin, it merges the entries into one output which I don't really want but it's not a dealbreaker.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items
LEFT JOIN   //left join
readStatus
ON  items.itemId = readStatus.itemId
WHERE (readStatus.status != 1 OR readStatus.status IS NULL);
```

Read the [**LEFT JOIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem and I learned about `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this sounds like something that would be better solved with EXIST rather than a (left) join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM readStatus
                  WHERE items.itemId = readStatus.itemId
                  AND readStatus.status = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN readStatus ON items.itemId = readStatus.itemId
WHERE readStatus.itemId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

WHERE readStatus IS NULL OR readStatus.status != -1

Answer (score 0):

You must use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN readStatus ON  items.itemId = readStatus.itemId and readStatus.status != 1;
```

How this will work.

It will take the all rows wrom items table when from readStatus will take only that that has matching itemId and are not in state 1.